# How do you deal with fixed resolution screenshots? (e.g. GUI screenshots)

Tags: graphics

In my LaTeX document I need to show some screenshots of a GUI, which has a fixed resolution (for example, 1200x600) and I cannot change it (not without much hassle). The text in such figures always appear crappy in my  documents to the point where it's almost impossible to read without zooming in/out to the figure's normal resolution. No need to say this gets even worse when you try to print the document.

I was curious as to what strategies you guys have in dealing with these oh so painful figures.

Is there a way to vectorize text automatically in a 2D GUI screenshot?

Comment: If you can’t change the GUI window’s size, this actually points to a really crappy GUI. On the other hand, Windows and Linux actually allow changing the GUI fonts’ DPI setting, effectively making GUI fonts larger (OS X probably allows this as well …).

Comment: @Konrad: It might be the screenshots, not the GUI, which are fixed in size? That size does certainly sound a bit bulky, though! (And I think OS X even has a way to take "screenshots" in PDF format directly?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question to post the following link : https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/archives/494-Better-PDF-screenshots-with-gtk-3.html

Apparently, gtk-3 apps allow easy conversion/printing of screenshots to PDF format, which is pretty neat, although it is limited only to gtk-3 apps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an easy way to vectorize text in the image. I'd suggest whether to show only the part with the text, or re-write that text into the document itself.

The resolution should be good if you want to print in a4 pages with a good quality.