# Selecting best file extension for graphics figures pictures

Tags: graphics

So, lets say I have the chance to **choose** which file extension I want for my figure/graphic/picture that I want to include in my work.

I went over [How do I insert an image in LaTeX so it looks good on print?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165/how-do-i-insert-an-image-in-latex-so-it-looks-good-on-print), but I wanted to know if this still applies for nowadays, and specially if given the chance to select the extension **at the source**... and if this also applies for electronic pdf documents (i.e., not printed)

Which one should I choose that brings the best results?

PS: This question has very nice complementary information:

[Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat/1075#1075)

Comment: I'am not sure I understand this question: It is not the extension, but the format (vectorized vs rasterized) that defines the quality. Both PDF and EPS can contain vector/raster images. (If, for instance, you scan some image into a PDF file, the extension is `.pdf`, but it's a raster graphics). The only crucial point is bitmap images and the difference between lossles PNG and loosy JPEG. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/how-to-embed-screenshots-properly/40858#40858) for the glory details.

Comment: If you havn't read this (you then should) question by Werner: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72930/graphics-file-extensions-and-their-order-of-inclusion-when-not-specified?rq=1 By utilizing that you can have all image formats and switch between them, quite easily! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what I recommend:

- Choose **PDF** format for drawings and material that is already vectorised (typical diagrams and simple drawings)
- Choose **PNG** for anything which is not vectorised but has fine details that should be exactly reproduced such as screenshots (it's looseless and therefore no artifacts will appear)
- for pictures/photos choose **JPEG**

I work with **pdflatex**.

**Examples**

Here's a photo. As **JPEG** it is about 140 KB and as **PNG** it is about 1200 KB. You cant't tell the difference:

**JPEG**
[image]

**PNG**
[image]

The next picture is a screenshot. As **PNG** it is clear - every pixel is exactly correct. The **PNG** size is 41 KB. The **JPEG** (I used a high compression obviously) is only 10 KB but you get artifacts. A **PNG** file will not loose information unless you change the resolution.

**PNG**
[image]

**JPEG** (high compression)
[image]

Comment: Can you tell a reason for *not* using PNG for photos?

Comment: @BenediktBauer PNG is more for pictures with “discontinuous” changes in colors.

Answer (score 0):

I use EPS for vectorized images. That way I can do manual editing in corel draw more easily than with PDF. Using epstopdf library will compile the EPS into PDF anyway