# Extract code LaTeX from a figure create with Inkscape

Tags: graphics, inkscape

I'm trying to understand how Inkscape works with LaTeX? What are the steps to export any figure drawn with this program in LaTeX language? Is the code TikZ or something else? Could someone suggest me how to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: Two possible ways: either save as pdf with separate text or export to tikz. For the later, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409231/36296

Comment: For the first option, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415825/36296

Comment: Can I see your step with the screenshots of the software please? For me is better of a link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok so here we go.

I decided to make this visual tutorial because some people are just more *cartesian*... Also because the extension has changed in the last years.

But don't be lazy, be sure to check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334393/75648) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409231/36296) too, and if you run into problems with text check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2107/75648).

First thing is to download the svg2tikz ([here](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz)), this should be pretty straightforward, just click on the green button and save (or open) the .zip file.

Open your windows explorer and go to `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\extensions`
it is inside this folder that the extension files will be drop, leave it open.

Open the zip file and navigate to `svg2tikz-master\svg2tikz\extensions\` it should look like this:

[image: 7zip with extension]

Select the first 3 files and drag'n'drop them to the folder you left open before. This should be `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\extensions`, and look like this:

[image: inkscape extension folder]

Once you done that, open Inkscape. Make your drawing and select `Save As...`

[image: random lines]

You may also use the Extension menu and go for Export, but you won't get to choose where the file is saved.

At the end of the list you will see `Tikz Code .tex` like this:

[image: save as tikz code]

In my example the image code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.056pt]
    (12.2944,5.9435) -- (23.2524,102.6950) .. controls (35.7691,59.6863) and
    (34.2478,-2.8197) .. (107.7096,38.8176);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

- download **svg2tikz** from https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz
- Extract the files `tikz_export.py, tikz_export_effect.inx, and tikz_export_output.inx` from `svg2tikz-master/svg2tikz/extensions` and put them in the **share/extension** directory inside the Inkscape installation directory, and it is in `/usr/share/inkscape/extensions` for ubuntu
- Draw desired picture in Inkscape
- Export from the menu: **Extension -> Export -> Export to TikZ path**

Comment: the extentions directory for Inkscape also can be `~/.config/inkscape/extensions`