# Best strategy to import and annotate CAD-drawings in Tikz

Tags: import, tikz-pic

I would like to import CAD-drawings into TikZ to add some annotations/arrows/... . My CAD-software is able to export drawings as DWG/DXF and PDF.

I could of course import the drawing as a picture and overwrite with TikZ, but what I want to achieve is to control line styles of the drawing inside the TikZ code to have a maximum of consistency in the document, even when i change the picture size!

What I already tried was to import the PDF into Inkscape and ungroup it into its seperate lines. But unfortunately I cannot find the TikZ-export feature everybody is talking about.

Do you have any ideas, how I could do it?

Greetings
Frieder

Comment: Here is described how to install the tikz export: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436209/extract-code-latex-from-a-figure-create-with-inkscape/436218#436218