# Image Quality (pgn, jpeg, PDF)

Tags: graphics, pdftex, jpeg

At the moment I am writing a document which will include a lot of screenshots. When I save and use the Screenshots as jpeg you can clearly see a loss of image quality.

What is the best method for this? 
Print the screenshot as PDF? But then I would have to trim the pdf for each picture to it's actual size.

Comment: Trim the image (don't leave any white border around), then save the image as PDF.

Comment: when saving the screenshot as pdf (for example in GIMP) the quality is worse than jpeg :/

Comment: Dulicate of [How to embed screenshots properly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/how-to-embed-screenshots-properly/40858#40858). Even though this question mentions LyX, the answers cover IMHO all aspects that are asked for.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The question you have asked has already been answered in the past, which is the reason it might get closed; please take a look at existing questions and answers  as the one I have linked to in my other comment. To find more just search for `screenshot`. If you find anything that has not yet been covered by existing answers, feel free to edit your question or ask a new one.

Comment: See also my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136087/selecting-best-file-extension-for-graphics-figures-pictures (Selecting best file extension for graphics figures pictures) The answer includes an example screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess for your task png is the best choice, since it can compress lossless and you won't see any artefacts. Most screenshot tools can generate png, otherwise you have to save as bmp and convert to png (the windows standard painting tool can do that). PDF will have no benefit for you, it will just wrap a container around your png or jpeg image.

If you are running linux and you are taking screenshots of GTK applications, there is an opportunity to take vector screenshots (e. g. in PDF format) as well, see https://gitorious.org/gtk-vector-screenshot.