# LyX enlarging inserted images

Tags: graphics, lyx, dimensions

I have a problem with inserting images in my thesis that I write with LyX. Images in exported pdf are always larger than they actually are.

Here is what it looks like in the editor, that's the real size of the image:

[image]

However in the pdf the image is larger and you can see the pixelation: (It isn't zoomed in the pdf reader, it's 100% size).

[image]

I've tried checking the checkbox and setting 100% size in the image's properties but that didn't help.

What do I need to do to have images in my thesis appear exactly the same size as they actually are?

Comment: Click on the image in LyX. Under the tab LaTeX and LyX options, what does it say under Scale on Screen?

Comment: 100%. The images in the editor are the right size.

Comment: What *is* the size of the image? From the screen shots, I assume you are inserting a bitmap image of, let's say, AxB pixels. The LyX editor renders it pixel-wise on the screen. However, in PDF, the entity "pixel" just does not exist – everything has to be a length unit, such as pt, mm or inch. So the PDF renderer takes another parameter into account, the "dots-per-inch" (actually pixels per inch) that tells him the assumed physical size of each pixel. It then **has** to scale it depending on the output device (printer, screen at various resolutions, and so on).

Comment: In other words, the _size_ in your _appear exactly the same size as they actually are_ is (and has to be) of a physical length unit and can never be "pixel". Take also a look at   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/how-to-embed-screenshots-properly/40858#40858

Comment: Oh, that is probably going to be my problem. Yes, the image is a bitmap image of a size 200x200 px and I wanted it to appear as a 200x200 px sized image in the pdf. I am making the images so I can make them as a vector graphics. This will be easier because I'll be able to scale them anyway I want, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the image with the <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> > <kbd>Settings..</kbd>

- <kbd>Graphics</kbd> tab > Set the image size in the PDF.

[image: snapshot2]

- <kbd>LaTeX and LyX options</kbd> tab > Set the image size in the screen.

[image: snapshot1]

**Suggestions:**

- Usually is better set a small scale for the screen as 10%, so you can still focus in the surrounding text and recognize the image. If you have intuitive file names for the images, even better: use the Draft Mode.
- Usually the safer option here is set the width of the image to a percentage of the line with of text as show the screenshot. With "safer" I mean that other options, said `Scale Graphics(%): 30%` or `Set With: 30 Text Widht %` could work for your page layout, but if you later change the layout (for example from one to two columns of text) most probably you will need to set the image size again.